# How far can i optimize the Below Code?

Tags: apex, trigger, delete

Problem Statement:
The apex code should prevent the account from getting deleted if it has associated/Related contact

```
public static void deletechild(Map<Id,account> mapacc){
        set <Id> setaccid = New set<Id>(mapacc.keySet());

        List<Account> liscondel = New List<Account>();
        for (AggregateResult ar :[select Count(Id) ContactCount,AccountID from Contact 
                                  where AccountId In:setaccid Group By accountId]){
            Account a = New Account();
                                      if ((Integer)ar.get('Contactcount') > 0){
                                          a = mapacc.get((id)ar.get('AccountId'));
                                          a.adderror('we cannot delete');
                                      }
                                      else{
                                          a = mapacc.get((id)ar.get('AccountId'));
                                          liscondel.add(a);
                                      }
            
        }
        Delete liscondel;
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a look at the below code and compare it with your code. Just try to understand things. According to me, you want to delete accounts without contacts.

```
public static void deletechild(Map<Id,account> accMap){
        List<Id> accIdListToDelete = New List<Id>();
        for (Account acc :[SELECT Id, (SELECT Id FROM Contacts) 
                           FROM Account 
                           WHERE Id IN: accMap.keySet()]){
            if(acc.Contacts.isEmpty()) {
                accIdListToDelete.add(acc.Id);
            }
        }
        Database.delete(accIdListToDelete);
    }
```